# Geometry of the map $\vec{u}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{u})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vectors

A linear map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined as $\vec{u}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{u})$ where $\vec{u}$ is a unit vector. What would its geometry look like?

I know that I can rewrite this map as $(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u})\vec{r}-(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{u} = \vec{r} - (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{u}$

However I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: What do you call *the geometry of a map*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net As in does it map to a line, is it a skew map, is it a rotation map, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{u}$ is the component of $\vec{r}$ along the unit vector $\vec{u}$. So $\vec{u}\times(\vec{r}\times\vec{u})
=\vec{r} - (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{u}$ is the component of $\vec{r}$ which is perpendicular to the unit vector $\vec{u}$.

The map is neither injective nor surjective. It is not injective because for $\vec{a}$ and for $\vec{a}+\lambda\vec{u}$ we get the same value for any real $\lambda$. It is not surjective because the range of the function doesn't contain any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has non zero component in the direction of $\vec{u}$ such as $\vec{u}$ itself.

Comment: So does this mean that the map will map all points on to a line that is perpendicular to $\vec{u}$?

Comment: @mp12853 It will map to a plane (not line) that is perpendicular to the direction of $\vec{u}$ and passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B= \{u, v, w\}$. In that basis, the matrix $M$ of $f$ is

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &  0\\
0 & 1 &  0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ which is the matrix of the projection on the plane orthogonal to $u$.